# Graphite Not Showing Recent Data

Tags: graphite, graphite-carbon

I have Graphite running on a Docker container and I've fed 24 hours worth of data sampled at 20 minute intervals to nine metrics – far from being a large payload. If I graph each metric in the Graphite web app, the last six hours of data are invisible. If I pull the raw data from the render API, these data points are indeed null (timestamps with no value).

However, if I narrow the time range down to the last six hours, the graphs display all the data I would expect. Weirder still, if I try to view this data using Grafana, the same thing happens: the last six hours are not shown unless I shrink the time range.

Is there any way to fix this so that recent data points are visible while viewing more than 6 hours of data?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the storage-schemas.conf and storage-aggregation.conf files.

Do you have a different retention after the 6 hour?

We had a similar issue with data disappearing after the first 24h where we had high resolution. We had to tune how data is aggregated to the "next level".

Or maybe it is just the data is not yet written to disk - and only exists in the carbon-cache at the moment.